# Scroll view doesn't show bottom part

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I have this relative layout that has a scroll view in it. But when the scroll view has more text in it, it doesn't show the bottom text, it goes behind my button. How can I fix this?

Here is what I've done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00AEEC"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:background="#00AEEC"
        android:padding="20dp" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/onlywithalcohol_heading_page2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/details_header"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_margin="20dp" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/details_country"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:text="USA"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/details_title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/details_country"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:text="Fastest Time To Drink A Pint Of Soda Water, Consume A Bowl Of Macaroni And Cheese With Chopsticks, Eat And Read A Fortune Cookie And Take A Shot Of Peach Schnapps "
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="#FFFF00" />

     <ScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_below="@id/details_title"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/details_description"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
             android:text="Sam Birdsong removed a cork from an empty bottle of wine using just a napkin in two minutes, 55.47 seconds.He stipulated beforehand that he had to begin with an unopened bottle, uncork it and pour out the wine, then shove the cork back inside the bottle and pull it out with a cloth napkin"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:background="#00AEEC"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/details_back_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:text="@string/back_btn"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have to use RelativeLayout ? why not using LinearLayout it should work for you

Comment: @Saksak now Im using linear layout but my button is off the screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your layout to be LinearLayout and it should work for you, you might need to use

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

to align the button at the very bottom of the screen

and you might need to use

```
android:layout_weight=""
```

if needed.

here is a block that you can place inside a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details_country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="USA"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/details_country"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Fastest Time To Drink A Pint Of Soda Water, Consume A Bowl Of Macaroni And Cheese With Chopsticks, Eat And Read A Fortune Cookie And Take A Shot Of Peach Schnapps "
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/details_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Sam Birdsong removed a cork from an empty bottle of wine using just a napkin in two minutes, 55.47 seconds.He stipulated beforehand that he had to begin with an unopened bottle, uncork it and pour out the wine, then shove the cork back inside the bottle and pull it out with a cloth napkin , and this wilk take for ever and ever out the wine, then shove the cork back inside the bottle and pull it out with a cloth napkin , and this wilk take for ever and ever out the wine, then shove the cork back inside the bottle and pull it out with a cloth napkin , and this wilk take for ever and ever out the wine, then shove the cork back inside the bottle and pull it out with a cloth napkin , and this wilk take for ever and ever "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/details_back_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=""
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="back"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the LinearLayout containing the Button, for example:

```
android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
```

Use this in the RelativeLayout containing the scrollView:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
```

Note that there is a bottom margin of 20dp, if you don't want it you could use android:layout_marginLeft, android:layout_marginRight and android:layout_marginTop to make sure you have the 20dp margin everywhere else.